# RRAS PPTP VPN Connected but not get ping my local LAN

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn, routing, rras

Two days back i had configure RRAS VPN server on Windows server 2008 Std R2 with two (LAN (192.168.100.173 with 255.255.255.0 subnet, without gateway,no DNS -- only ip Address was there) / WAN (Complete set of IP address/Subnet/GW/DNS had provided by ISP)) different NIC Interface, not a part of windows domain(ADDS), had install NPS/Routing and Remote Access Roles on to the same. I have edit **Netowk policy** under "NPS(Local) --> Policys --> Netowk policy (Connections to ms routing and remote access server) enable it & grant access" to the same. Rest the things are default in NPS.

Go to Routing and remote access property --> ipv4 --> change IPv4 address assignment to static & add "173.30.30.1 upto 173.30.30.10". Ten IP for VPN USers. Tick on "Enable broadcast name resolution"..Adapter "Allow RAS to Select adapter", Rest of the things are default in all the tabs. I have created a user on local (RRAS) server, allow access in Dial-in Tab.

Now i had tried to connect VPN through the same, i have connected successfully with details :

PPP adapter RRAS_VPN:

```
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : WAN (PPP/SLIP) Interface
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-53-45-00-00-00
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 173.30.30.2
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 173.30.30.2
    NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

C:\Documents and Settings\User>

But i am not able to ping or access any resource of my office.

Is there any thing left or need to done from my side to resolve this issue. i have different range of IP address (like: 192.168.1.0/192.168.2.0/...192.168.45.0..etc).

Plz suggest ASAP....Thx in advance.

Comment: Did you enable LAN Routing in RRAS?

Comment: How to enable LAN Routing the same?

Comment: I don't have a RRAS server handy. It's somewhere in the properties or configuration of the RRAS server. If I rememeber correctly, it's a check box somewhere.

Comment: ok what i did...i disable the Routing and remote access & tried to reconfigure the same & i have found it under custom (VPN & LAN Routing), mark ok and configure the same...then i tried tried to connect vpn its connected...but no success...Any thing else

Comment: Any Clue on it??? Any one??

Comment: please paste: ROUTE PRINT from vpn server, TRECERT from vpn client to office computer, TRACERT from office computer to vpn client

Comment: Ia m not able to paste due to limitation of words...any other option to send the same